# How to dynamically insert a ul into after a particular number of li?

Tags: jquery

I have a group of `li`'s like follwoing

```
        <ul class="clear_group>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>

    </ul>
```

I want to dynmacially add `ul` into the fourth number of `li` and also want to close the `/ul`  after the 7th number of `li`

Then , it shows like the following

```
        <ul class="clear_group>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>

        </ul>
        <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>

    </ul>
```

This is my Jquery,

```
        $( '.myclass ul li:nth-child(4)' ).after('</ul><ul class="clear_social">');
    $( '.myclass ul li:nth-child(7)' ).after('<ul>');
```

But the `<ul>` automatically close after the 4th  li  like `<ul class="clear_social"></ul>`

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM manipulation does not work like string concatenation, instead you need to create new `ul` elements are move those `li` to them like

```
var $ul = $('.clear_group'), $lis = $ul.children().slice(4), $next = $ul;
for(var i=0;i<$lis.length;i+=4){
    $next = $('<ul />').append($lis.slice(i, i+4)).insertAfter($ul)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tL5dmLo9/)

Comment: Many many thanks for ur answer, its working well,Thanks again, Can I add a Class="hello" into the newly created ul's?. Can you please update?